# What language techniques are used in this well-known quote from Macbeth?

Tags: literary-techniques

What language techniques are used in this famous quote by the Witches from Macbeth:
'Fair is foul, and foul is fair'

Comment: Sounds like homework to me.

Comment: it's not homework

Comment: @Abdulrahman It would be helpful for you to do more research and more narrowly define the scope of the question. For example, if you were to ask, "Why is this quote an example of (technique)?" and provide a definition of that term, we could help you figure it out. Even minimally, if you further defined what you mean by "language techniques" (rhetoric? grammar?) and gave a researched guess or two, someone might help you out. However, as it is it would be hard to answer the question without doing an exhaustive analysis and listing *every language technique at play*. That's way too broad.

Answer (score 3):

This is [antimetabole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimetabole): the repetition of words, but in a reversed order. For example in the sentence

> "I *meant* what I *said*, and I *said* what I *meant*." — Dr. Seuss, Horton Hatches the Egg

The words *meant* and *said* appear twice, the second time in reversed order.

The same pattern is clear in your quote.

Comment: Is this also seen in Alice and Wonderland? They contrast the differences - _'you might as well say I see what I eat is the same thing as I eat what I see!'_